# add a edit button and a delete button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a student registration system using angularjs.when I fill the form and click add it will add a student to a table and I have make a link using $routeprovider to see the list of students registered and now I need to edit the details of a added student.I have provided a link name Edit in each row of registered students how I can do it.

When that link is clicked I need to open a form filled with the existing details in relevant fields. How can I??

Comment: Provide the fiddle ?Share the code, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: thank you I got ma answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give us your work for more detail, but I think this link will help you https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

```
    ...
phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
      });
  }]);
```

Comment: thank you that link helped me :)